# Is there any way to use ngForm for div elements in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Is there any way to use ngForm for some elements (not `form` element)?

```
// ERROR
<div #sampleForm="ngForm">
  ...
</div>
```

I've heard `form` elements have an instance of ngForm applied and it provides some features. But I want to know how to get an instance of ngForm in some elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div ngForm #sampleForm="ngForm">
...
</div>
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts

Selector spec from that file:

```
selector: 'form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup]),ngForm,[ngForm]',
```

Comment: Super useful as sometimes using actual <form> tags causes issues in browsers like Safari/IE where requests that are triggered by button presses in them (not tied to a submit event) cause CORS to fail